# Origin of Exponential function

Tags: linear-algebra

This might be an odd question, but how was the exponential function $e$ actually discovered?

We can easily say that $\pi$ was discovered when they(primitive people) divided the circumference of the circle by its diameter, but I'm unable to link any incidents like this to the origin of $e$.

Looking up on the internet I saw something about the calculation of interest rates linked to $e$, but I was unable to understand it, some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Fun fact, $\pi$ is the greek letter pi, not just something mathematicians was fun to call "pie". Also, the number $e$ comes up fairly quickly once you start differentiating and doing calculus in general.

Comment: You can see the post [on-the-use-and-origins-of-the-constant-e](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/on-the-use-and-origins-of-the-constant-e).

Comment: See also [the number $e$](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html).

Comment: Why "linear algebra" ?

Comment: Finally, there is a full book on $e$: Eli Maor, [$e$: The Story of a Number](https://books.google.it/books?id=rCGM6TKHyboC&printsec=frontcover).